# Validation_errors() not showing in the view (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm working with my first application with CI and I'm having problems with the library [`form_validation`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-error-messages).

The validation and my method are working fine, except for the fact that I can't get to show my error messages. I tried to show them individually, as the manual said, but didn't work. Tried to show them using `echo validation_errors();`, but the error messages are blank in my page.

So I make a test to put the code in the controller and they work! But they are shown in the beginning of the page. I used some javascript to make it visually better (moved it to where I want it to be shown), but it's not beautiful. I tried everything on the CodeIgniter and still did not get a good result. Please, someone could help me on this?

This is my controller **User.php**:

```
public function registrar() {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->view('registrar');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Nome', 'trim|required|min_length[7]',
             array( 'required'      => '<br>- Por favor, insira seu nome.',
                    'min_length'    => '<br>- Por favor, insira seu nome completo.'));
        // ..... other rules


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

            $data = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'password' => $password_hash
            );
            if ($this->user_model->insertUser($data))
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg','<p>Ok</p>');
                redirect('user/registrar');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg','<p>Not ok</p>');
                redirect('user/registrar');
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            echo validation_errors('<div class="error">', '</div>'); //THIS LINE WORKS!!!
        }
    }
```

This is my view **registrar.php**:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="pure-form"> // using this only for css styling
            <?php echo validation_errors(); ?> // THIS LINE DOESN'T WORKS :(
            <?php echo form_open('user/registrar');?>
            <fieldset>
                <h1>Registrar</h1>
                <div class="pure-control-group group gr-2">
                    <label for="email">Nome:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nome" value="<?php echo set_value('name');?>">
                </div>
                // ....... everything else
            <input type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary verde" value="Cadastrar" name="register_submit">
            </div>
         <?php echo form_close();?>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading view page before the validation. That's the reason validation_errors are not showing in registrar.php.

$this->load->view('registrar');
Add this after else condition of validation or end of the function.